# How to list all mounts that start with a given prefix/root

Tags: shell-script, regular-expression

I am trying to look through `/proc/mounts` and return all mounts that start with a certain prefix or base directory, eg. `/run/media`. Right now one prefix is fine, but in principle it would be nice to be able to specify more than one.

`grep -o /run/media /proc/mounts` returns only `/run/media` as many times as present. If the regex part is `/run/media[\S]*` (to try and match the full path until a space) it still returns the same results as before.

Ultimately I'd like to output all of the matches formatted with a text prefix and quotes, as:

`"fs:/run/media/user/device1" "fs:/run/media/user/device2"` etc

Comment: If you want to return all mounts that start with `/run/media` then why not just remove the `-o` and just `grep /run/media /proc/mounts`?.

Comment: @NasirRiley That returns the whole line. I just want `/run/media/*`

Comment: Then just pipe the `grep` into `awk` with the column where `/run/media` appears. I'm not at one of my Linux machines right now but if it appears in the first column then `grep` then just `grep /run/media /proc/mounts | awk '{print $1}'`. There are other ways that this can be done but I'll have to wait until I have one of my Linux VMs.

Comment: `grep /run/media /proc/mounts | awk '{print $2}'` works but wouldn't it be more robust to have a regex that matches from the desired prefix until whitespace?

Comment: That is what it's doing. `awk` uses white space as the field separator unless otherwise specified by the `-F` switch so it prints that field between the white spaces which are the delimiters. The same result can be given with one command but I'll have to wait until I have one of my VMs.

Comment: `grep -o '/run/media/[^[:space:]]*'` or `grep -Po '/run/media/\S*'`

Comment: `[\S]` matches a literal backslash or `S`.

Comment: Of course! Just using `'/run/media[^[:space:]]*'` or even `'/run/media\S*'` works perfectly. The `awk` solution also works, but isn't it better not to depend on the formatting of the input file, i.e. hard-coding the second column with `$2` ?

Answer (score 0):

```bash
foo () {
    awk '{ print $2 }' /proc/mounts |
    while read -r mountpoint; do
        for pattern do
            if [[ $mountpoint == $pattern ]]; then
                printf '%s:\t%s\n' "$pattern" "$mountpoint"
                break
            fi
        done
    done
}
```

This `bash` function parses out the second column, the mount point, from `/proc/mounts` and then proceeds to compare each of the given arguments as shell patterns against each of the mount points.  For each match, the pattern matching and the mount point is printed and the next mount point is considered.  The output format is easily changed by changing the `printf` command.

Example run on an Ubuntu system I have access to (note that the patterns are filename globbing patterns and that patterns that contain globbing characters need to be protected from the shell by quoting).

```
$ foo /sys '/sys/*' '*info*'
/sys:   /sys
/sys/*: /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
/sys/*: /sys/fs/fuse/connections
/sys/*: /sys/fs/pstore
/sys/*: /sys/kernel/debug
/sys/*: /sys/kernel/debug/tracing
/sys/*: /sys/kernel/security
*info*: /proc/cpuinfo
*info*: /proc/meminfo
/sys/*: /sys/fs/cgroup
/sys/*: /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd
/sys/*: /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event
/sys/*: /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct
/sys/*: /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb
/sys/*: /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer
/sys/*: /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio
/sys/*: /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset
/sys/*: /sys/fs/cgroup/pids
/sys/*: /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio
/sys/*: /sys/fs/cgroup/memory
/sys/*: /sys/fs/cgroup/devices
```

I chose to use a shell loop in the function to read the output from the `awk` program instead of doing the matching in the `awk` program itself (which would normally be what I would have done). I did that because I wanted to have a simple way of iterating over the patterns and using the `==` operator in `bash`.

By the way, if you'd like to use extended regular expressions instead, just change the `==` in the function to `=~`, but remember that you would have to anchor the expression with `^` and `$` to match a *specific* path (as in `^/sys$`), otherwise the expression would match anywhere in the pathname.

Comment: Thanks. What would be the tradeoffs compared to `PAT="/mnt|/run/media"; if [ -n "$PAT" ]; then grep -Eo "($PAT)\S*" /proc/mounts | sed -r 's/(.*)/ fs:\1 /' | tr -d '\n'; fi` , which so far seems to get exactly what I want. Firstly, it does not depend on the input being consistently formatted, and secondly it is easy to specify multiple prefixes with alternation. Thoughts?

Comment: @adatum That command would not only look in the second column of `/proc/mounts` so would also match `/mnt` or `/run/media` anywhere on the lines, and would therefore return a mount on `/somedisk/mnt` (and it would return most mount points if your pattern was `rw` when you wanted to find a mount that contained that string). It would also be impossible to match the single `/sys` mount point in my example.

Comment: @adatum Mount points are pathnames, so it makes more sense to use filename globbing patterns than regular expressions.

Comment: `/sys` is captured when I run it, but nice catch about `/somedisk/mnt`. How about trying to anchor to word boundaries with `\b` in grep's regular expression?

Comment: It seems `\b` does not consider `/` a word character. What about using the regex `"\s($PAT)\S*"`. Requiring whitespace before the prefix means it will not match subdirectories, though it will also fail to match at the start of the line. That is not a problem in this case, but it would be more elegant if the entire path can be considered a single word at match against its beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative for you.  My `awk` skills are nascent, and I would appreciate any feedback on how to refine the usage shown here.

```
show_mount_prefix() {

# $1 is a directory prefix.  Display all current mounts that have that prefix.

  printf '"%s" ' $(mount | awk -v prefix=" on ${1}[/ ]" '$0~prefix {print $3}')
  printf '\n'
}
```

With no argument, `show_mount_prefix()` displays all mount points [line breaks added for readability]:

```
$ show_mount_prefix 
"/sys" "/proc" "/dev" "/dev/pts" "/run" "/" "/sys/kernel/security" 
"/dev/shm" "/run/lock" "/sys/fs/cgroup" "/sys/fs/cgroup/unified" 
"/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd" "/sys/fs/pstore" "/sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event" 
"/sys/fs/cgroup/memory" "/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct" "/sys/fs/cgroup/pids" 
"/sys/fs/cgroup/devices" "/sys/fs/cgroup/freezer" "/sys/fs/cgroup/blkio" 
"/sys/fs/cgroup/rdma" "/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset" "/sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio" 
"/sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb" "/dev/mqueue" "/sys/kernel/debug" 
"/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc" "/dev/hugepages" "/sys/kernel/debug/tracing" 
"/sys/fs/fuse/connections" "/sys/kernel/config" "/snap/core/7270" 
"/snap/core/7396" "/data" "/var/lib/lxcfs" "/run/user/370880" "/run/user/0"
```

With an argument:

```
$ show_mount_prefix /dev
"/dev" "/dev/pts" "/dev/shm" "/dev/mqueue" "/dev/hugepages"
```

It is regrettable that this algorithm doesn't intuitively handle the argument `/` which presumably would list all mounts, the same as in the no-argument case.  It did at one time, but the addition of the `[/ ]` atom in the `awk` pattern broke that.  That atom is necessary given that the OP doesn't want `/d` to match `/dev` and `/data` and the like.